# How to perform Ant path mapping in a 'war' task?

Tags: java, ant

I have several JAR file pattern sets, like

```
<patternset id="common.jars">
 <include name="external/castor-1.1.jar" />
 <include name="external/commons-logging-1.2.6.jar" />
 <include name="external/itext-2.0.4.jar" />
     ...
</patternset>
```

I also have a 'war' task containing a lib element:

```
<lib dir="${src.dir}/jars">
  <patternset refid="common.jars"/>
  <patternset refid="web.jars"/>
     ...
</lib>
```

Like this however, I end up with WEB-INF/lib containing the subdirectories from my patterns:

```
WEB-INF/lib/external/castor-1.1.jar
WEB-INF/lib/external/...
```

Is there any way to flatten this, so the JAR files appear at the top-level under WEB-INF/lib, regardless of the directories specified in the patterns? I looked at `mapper` but it seems you cannot use them inside `lib`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use mappedresources element (Ant 1.8+)

```
<mappedresources>
  <!-- Fileset here -->
  <globmapper from="external/*.jar" to="*.jar"/>
</mappedresources>
```

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#mappedresources

If you have a typical web project it is better to split the web-app libraries and general-purpose libraries in different folders and leave WEB-INF/lib to have only those needed at runtime. This way you'll avoid collisions and also your project will look much clearer to other developers.

Answer (score 9):

I was dissatisfied with having to manually generate a WAR directory or declare library subdirectories, so I came up with this. Seems to work, obviously you'll need to adjust it to your own needs:

```
<war destfile="build/output.war" webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
    <fileset dir="${web.dir}" />
    <mappedresources>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
        <chainedmapper>
            <flattenmapper/>
            <globmapper from="*.jar" to="WEB-INF/lib/*.jar" />
        </chainedmapper>
    </mappedresources>
</war>
```

Comment: It's a little counter-intuitive not to have a lib element but this is good.  One point to reiterate in case it isn't obvious to others, <mappedresources> replaces <lib>.  The war task is an extension of the jar/zip tasks and the lib, classes, webinf and metainf elements are all FileSets that Ant puts in their respective locations in the generated war file.  This solution omits the lib element and "manually" places the jars in WEB-INF/lib/.